# Conditionally Using Request Parameters for skip and limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've implemented 'limit' and 'skip' queries for my restful API.

If I try to do

**'localhost:4000/api/users?skip=60'**, it will skip the first 60 items in my data

and

**'localhost:4000/api/users?limit=5'**, will only return 5 data

and then combining these two

**'localhost:4000/api/users?skip=60&limit=5'** will skip the first 60 data and return only 5 from that point.

**My skip and limit are implemented as :**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var skipping = req.query.skip;
    var limiting = req.query.limit;

    // skipping

    if(skipping != null){
        user.find({})
        .skip(3)
        .exec(function(err, users) {
            if(err){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: err,
                    data: []
                });
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'OK skipped',
                    data: users
                });
            }
    });
    }

    // limit

    else if(limiting != null){
        user.find({})
        .limit(parseInt(limiting))
        .exec(function(err, users) {
            if(err){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: err,
                    data: []
                });
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'OK limited',
                    data: users
                });
            }
    });
    }
  }
});
```

Each of them works fine, but when I try to combine them by chaning else if to if, the app crashes giving a message

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

What is the way to combine those queries without errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't rewrite the code for each parameter change. The [`.skip()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and [`.limit()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) modifiers basically modify the "cursor" and can be "chained. More specifically, with mongoose they return a `Query` object, which again you just "chain" before you issue [`.exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec). Or really just use "defaults":

Using defaults:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var skipping = parseInt(req.query.skip) || 0;
    var limiting = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 0;

    user.find().skip(skipping).limit(limiting).exec(...);

})
```

Or "chaining":

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var skipping = req.query.skip;
    var limiting = req.query.limit;

    let query = user.find();

    // Chain skip
    if (skipping != undefined)             // purely since 0 is "falsey"
      query = query.skip(parseInt(skipping));

    // Chain limit
    if (limiting != undefined)
      query = query.limit(parseInt(limiting));

    // Then exec
    query.exec(...);

})
```

This is "method chaining" and you actually use it *"all the time"*, it's just that you don't realize you are using it. For example, without the `if` conditions:

```
let query = user.find().skip(0).limit(0);
```

Is **exactly** the same as writing:

```
let query = user.find();
query = query.skip(0);
query = query.limit(0);
```

In the first form each "modifier" `find()`, `skip()` and `limit()` ALL return a `Query` object based on the input object they were given. They "return to the left" as they are simply a `function`, and this is what enables you to "chain". So writing the assignments "separately" is *"exactly the same thing"* in terms of the assignments actually made.

At any rate the `req.params` values are either present or `undefined` and **NOT** `null` as you are currently trying to do. Hence the error for calling `res.send()` **twice**.

But you don't even need to repeat the code issuing the query. Simply do it **"once"** using either method as shown.

Comment: I tried your 'chaining' option and it worked! But I don't quite understand how the solution works. 'if(skipping) query = query.skip(parseInt(skipping))' in this line, is it incrementing a string value to the query, so that all query options are concatenated?

Comment: @Dawn17 No it "modifies" how the request is actually sent. Nothing actually happens until you `.exec()`, and that's the part you don't seem to be grasping. Personally I'd set "defaults" for this type of thing, but it's useful to "understand" how the components actually work. A "query" is just a "query" until you actually "execute" it.

Comment: I am saying if both `skipping` and `limiting` exist, would `query` be replaced by 'query = query.limit(parseInt(limiting))' since it happens after `if(skipping)` ?

Comment: @Dawn17 Not "replaced" but "append". These are "options", and as I have explained twice already *"Nothing gets sent to the server until you execute"*. So if "both" are there, then they are "both" applied. I suppose if I wanted to get technical you would `if(skipping != undefined)` instead since `0` is a "falsey" value as well. But we're talking about whether you actually sent the paramters or not more than "what value" they have. Also "Read the documentation", which is why I put the links in the answer. `.sklip()` and `limit()` have "return values" which is the "modified" object.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the explanation. Lastly, if we want to return a data that returns a different format such as length of the data (count), I assume that using this method won't work because this is something that has to be specified inside. Can a query something like `count` be implemented as they way you stated?

Comment: @Dawn17 `count()` is "also a modifier". I actually added more text to the answer to explain what "method chaining" actually is, and how you actually use it all the time, but just don't seem to realize that is what you are doing.

Comment: I would really like to say thank you so much for a great explanation!